# Easiest way to implement a "Was this article helpful?" convention in docs sites?

Tags: user-feedback

I need a way to allow users to rate the helpfulness of documentation articles on our docs site. Usabilla is an example of a tool that is created for this (and other things). What other ways exist for collecting and tracking this kind of information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the depth of the information you would like to collect. If you want to know what volume of users find your article useful it`s enough to use a simple javascript where users can press thumbs up or down on each article or use Usabilla or other competitors of their for more indepth data on users.